# Force data-card-type styling on Embedly card

Tags: embedly

I'm using the paid version of [Embedly Cards](http://docs.embed.ly/docs/cards). In an overview we are displaying all the links added to specific posts. Now we are using the standard cards which are using a lot of space (+/- height 500px) per post in our overview.

Embedly cards with the attribute `data-card-type="article"` are much smaller (+/- height 200px) than the basic version. Only if we use this attribute to force every card to be smaller, the video's won't be embedded, but only linked to, for example YouTube. So you have to go away from our platform to view the video instead of viewing in directly on our platform.

Now we want to force all the standard links to 'article'-cards, but keep the bigger design for video cards. Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reply of Embed.ly**

Thanks for checking in, there's not a way to do this directly as we would need to know the setting prior to knowing the type of content. Card customizations can be found here: http://docs.embed.ly/docs/cards#customize

If you need a custom display and have some experiences with using APIs, I suggest checking out our Embed API: embed.ly/embed, http://docs.embed.ly/docs/oembed

Art

--

Concluding: not possible with cards, possible with the API

Comment: Can you give an example of customization, e.g. how to use data-card-image, having a hard time finding one